# Mac OS Virtual Box performances

Tags: performance, virtualization, virtualbox

If you run Mac OS 10.8 with Virtual Box (on Linux), on a computer that supports hardware virtualization, how good will be the performances?

With a powerful computer (i7, 8gb of ram, ssd hd), would you be able to run music softwares like Ableton Live, Traktor, etc...?

Comment: OS X's EULA doesn't allow virtualization of OS X on other operating systems.

Comment: I know that, but I bought a Mac and a 10.8 licence, and although they try to make me, I disagree with their policy which I find not really legal. Since I paid for hardware and software, I believe I can do what I want with what I own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes performance is excellent with hardware virtualisation. Ableton, pro tools, cubase all run great on i5.

Comment: Cool I will give it a try! any good resource on how to go about setting up virtualbox for best results?

Comment: @Piero: This is rather old, but for future reference VirtualBox can use hardware virtualization, but a hypervisor like KVM is going to do a good bit better in terms of performance. I use virtualbox locally on my linux machine, and it works great for simple things like hosting virtual server environments where I'm only using a shell and realtime performance isn't an issue. As for serious applications KVM is probably the very best bet. If you just want to toy with VM's then VirtualBox is great, but if you plan on running ableton use KVM.